# What is the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality?

Tags: inequality

So I've been thinking of doing some Olympiad math (USAMO, USAJMO) in the future and am trying to prepare for it. One concept I don't quite understand is the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. Most likely I will need to use it in sums if I approach it. I know that there are many forms of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but what is the sum form of it?

I am in middle school, but I will still understand sums written as $\sum$.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), which includes some forms that involve sums (see the "Special cases" section)? It would be better for you to explain what exactly you don't understand, so we can better help you beyond just stating the inequality.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the formula means...

Comment: It's just equivalent to saying the meaningless "I don't understand anything", since Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is simply a "formula". Which part or notation in the formula do you not understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality states that for all vectors $u$ and $v$ of an inner product space it is true that
>   $$\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|\leq\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|.$$

If, in particular, the inner product space is $\mathbb C^n$, which has inner product

$$\langle u,v\rangle=\langle\left(u_1,u_2,\dots,u_n\right),\left(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\right)\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\bar v_k,$$

then the above inequality becomes

$$\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\bar v_k\right|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left|u_k\right|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n\left|v_k\right|^2}=\left\|u\right\|\left\|v\right\|.$$

Comment: I mean the sum version...

Comment: The inequality is much more clear using the vector notation given here. But if you want to avoid using vector notation, you can express everything in terms of the components of $u$ and $v$, which yields $| \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i | \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2}$. This way of writing it conceals how intuitive the inequality is, though, if one is familiar with vectors.